# Building a docker image using AWS Developer Tools

Tags: docker, aws-code-deploy, amazon-ecs, aws-codecommit, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to build a simple app using only AWS (free-tier only if possible). The challenge right now is around Continuous integration.
I have a simple repository in AWS CodeCommit containing a DockerFile representing my base image.
This base image will be used later in a different app deployed onto AWS ECS.

1) How can I automatically, using only the AWS stack (no Jenkins etc.), build my base docker image on each commit and then deploy it to AWS ECR?

2) For the app built on top of this image, how can I, on each commit, build the app docker image, update the ECS Task to specify the latest tag, and re-run the task?

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing because I don't see how it is possible... Obviously I have CodeCommit, ECS and ECR running. I just don't know how to make them work together in a CI fashion...

Comment: +1 I'm stuck with the same problem. As you said CodeCommit->Jenkins->ECR. But then CodeCommit can deploy to only running EC2 instances. I'm trying still.

Comment: @tibo, I have similar setup using Github (but CodeCommit should also work), CodePipeline to orchestrate the CI/CD pipeline, CodeBuild to build and publish the artifacts on ECR, and CloudFormation to deploy on ECS. They work together really nice.

Comment: @nanestev Sounds awesome! Codebuild didn't exist when I wrote the question. That was the missing piece. :)